# Can a healthy pecan tree grow from the root of one which was cut down?

Tags: trees, growth

I had a pecan tree, which was more than 20 years old.  I cut it down because the trunk near the ground was partially rotted and the tree did not look healthy, though not dead.  Now a new tree (about 3 feet tall now) is growing out of the old root and it looks healthy.  I would love to keep it as long as it is going to be a healthy tree.  Is it worth saving it?

Comment: It would help to know what was ailing the old tree - they're generally long lived

Comment: It also would be helpful to know why you'd like to keep it. Are you primarily interested in having the tree for shade, or do you want to be able to harvest the pecans?

Answer (score 2):

Disease not withstanding and if nothing else is wrong the tree will grow, but it will never regain its former glory. Except for a select few species like locusts and aspens, trees that develop from suckers never do much of anything except annoy.